# How to edit moodle sql to time access

Tags: mysql, moodle

I'm trying to change my Moodle in 2.6 version. 
I want to do something like this: When user is logged in ,He have permission to watch all materials but only when his account is active. 
I want to edit sql database to add 1 field 'is_active' and set there datetime stamp.
For Example I have user John Doe , i put in database in field 'is_active' date 25.02.2014 and he can watch all lessons ans stuff till 25.02.2014 after that his account goes unactivate and when he tries to log in he will have information that his account is not active and he has to contact with administrator.

Can you tell me witch Database query change to check that permission when user is trying to log in ? I think that resolution will be to get current date from server and check it with date in database. If system date is lower that database user have access , if date is higher user doesn't have access and he gets info.

If somebody doesn't understand sorry for my english write in comments i will try to describe more.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a user profile field 'is_active', choose datetime and set it to 'Not visible'

site admin -> users -> accounts -> user profile fields

http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/User_profile_fields

Then create a local plugin that uses cron to check the date and sets the user to suspended

In /local/is_active/version.php - http://docs.moodle.org/dev/version.php

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$plugin->version = 201402301; // Plugin version
$plugin->requires = 2013051402; // Moodle version.
$plugin->component = 'local_is_active'; // Component name
$plugin->cron = 1; // In seconds - how often should this be run?
```

In /local/is_active/lang/en/local_is_active.php

```
$string['pluginname'] = 'Is active';
```

In /local/is_active/lib.php have a cron function local_xxx_cron() that updates the user table to suspended. I haven't tested the SQL but something like this

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

function local_is_active_cron() {
    $sql = "UPDATE {user}
            SET suspended = :suspended
            WHERE EXISTS (SELECT userid
                          FROM {user_info_field} f
                          JOIN {user_info_data} d ON d.fieldid = f.id
                              AND d.data < :now
                              AND d.userid = mdl_user
                          WHERE f.shortname = :shortname)";
    $params = array('suspended' => 1, 
        'now' => time(),
        'shortname' => 'is_active');
    $DB->execute($sql, $params);
}
```

EDIT : Forgot to add that you will need to go to notifications to install the plugin -  site admin -> notifications - then Moodle will automatically call the cron function when cron is run.

You can run cron manually by going to /admin/cron.php

As a site admin you can edit the date via the users profile - go to site admin -> users -> accounts -> browse list of users -> then click the pencil next to a user profile

Or update the date using something like this - the data field needs to be a unix timestamp rather than a string type date

```
$activedate = strtotime('2014-02-23'); // Timestamp
$fieldid = $DB->get_field('user_info_field', 'id', array('shortname' => 'is_active'));
$params = array('fieldid' => $fieldid, 'userid' => $userid);
if ($DB->record_exists('user_info_data', $params)) {
    $DB->set_field('user_info_data', 'data', $activedate, $params);
} else {
    $data = new stdClass();
    $data->fieldid = $fieldid;
    $data->userid = $userid;
    $data->data = $activedate;
    $data->dataformat = 0;
    $DB->insert_record('user_info_data', $data);
}
```

Comment: Wow ,thanks for help. I assume that after write that plugin i have only to put date into database and cron will be checking it every X seconds ?

Comment: And 1 more question , where exacly in database I can add that date to edit by cron ? (i think that i found it in mdl_user_info_data , I added date in fieldid number 11 (is_active have id=11) in data i added 2014-02-22 and this is not working, user can log in and nothing happens

Comment: If you set data to a timestamp - then run the cron manually - the user should then be suspended :) I've updated the code above.

Comment: Nice , thank you a lot. I will see witch type exacly i can edit via sql database. If I will have any question i will write here. :)

Comment: It's not working, i changed date to timestamp , now i changed time to timestamp and in data for fieldid and user i wish to lock everything looks ok. I started cron few times and I can still login for locked user

Comment: maybe it's cron problem , from cron.php i get:Processing customized cron scripts ...Processing cron function for local_is_active...
... started 00:29:59. Current memory use 47.9MB. 

cron didn't gave me Done info

Comment: Can you tell me how to debug local scripts in moodle ? 
In plugin you wrote when I'm trying to enter {moodlesite}/local/is_active/lib.php I got blank screen, i can't var_dump any function or variable , script doesn't work And I want to figure out why

Comment: Put these 2 lines in your config.php file to debug - 
$CFG->debug = 32767;
$CFG->debugdisplay = 1;

but lib.php should only containg functions - lib means library - it shouldn't be accessed directly

Comment: Sorry I was thinking about {siteurl}/local/is_active/version.php

Comment: that shouldn't be accessed directly either, what is it that you are trying to do? maybe open another question?

Comment: It's about code you wrote. It's not working and I'm trying to figure out why.
I got info from cron ".Processing cron function for local_is_active... ... started 00:29:59. Current memory use 47.9MB"
It's not ending so i want to repair it